# Error with Linq to Firebird Embedded (EF6.1 code first)

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first, firebird, entity-framework-6

I'm getting an `Unknown data type` error with Firebird Embedded when I try to use Linq to query the context.

It only seems to fail when Linq generates a parameterized query to send to the database; if the value is hard-coded, it works fine.  Also, it only fails on my Code First database; if I create the database first, it works.  However, I'm trying to learn Code First so creating the database isn't an option.

```cs
using (var context = new FirebirdDbContext(connectionString))
{
    context.Users.Add(new User()
    {
        Created = DateTime.Now,
        Name = "smith"
    });
    context.SaveChanges();

    bool found = context.Users.Any(u => u.Name == "smith");    // this works
    string name = "smith";
    found = context.Users.Any(u => u.Name == name);    // exception
}
```

The rest of the application is the same as in my [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959450/unknown-data-type-error-with-firebird-embedded-and-entity-framework-6) except I'm now using Entity Framework 6.1.0.  In fact, the error is the same too, but the cause is different.

I'd be surprised if this were a bug in the Firebird library (and I don't see it listed in their bug tracker).  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:**  The bug still occurs with the Firebird ADO.NET Provider (for Entity Framework 6) version 4.1.5.0.

Comment: What Firebird server you're running?

Comment: @cincura.net The error occurs with Firebird Embedded so there is no server.  I'm using the latest version from NuGet: Firebird ADO.NET Data provider (Entity Framework 6) version 4.1.0.0.

Comment: @vincentj Even Firebird Embedded has a version number. Which version of Firebird Embedded are you using?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Oh sorry, I forgot those did not come from NuGet!  fbembed.dll and ib_util.dll are version 2.5.2.26540.  The ICU DLLs are verson 3.0.0.0.

Comment: I just tried it with Firebird 3.0 Alpha 2 (version 3.0.0.30809) as well as the latest snapshot build (3.0.0.30988) and both produce the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the data provider, which has been [logged in the Firebird issue tracker](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-550).  The reporter of that bug has kindly [provided a fix](https://github.com/zabulus/NETProvider/commit/bb8ae84ad4dafca7c709f5ad39cba66f5bd9ba20).

The fix has not yet been incorporated into the official release, but I was able to [download the provider source](https://github.com/cincuranet/NETProvider) and apply the fix to get past this issue with my application.

Answer (score 0):

There is too few information.

Try mapping all tables and columns names to uppercase, using ToTable and HasColumnName in fluent mappings.

When I did that most of weird errors gone away when I was validating the compatibility of Entity framework and Firebird 2.5 embeded.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately it didn't work. I even tried mapping to ridiculous names thinking maybe I was using reserved words, but I still got the error.  By the way, there are more details about my program [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959450/unknown-data-type-error-with-firebird-embedded-and-entity-framework-6) (it's just a tiny sample app).  I was trying to avoid polluting this post with too much information.